# How to Retrieve Recommended video using YouTubeQuery.?

Tags: c#, youtube.net-api

How I can Retrieve Recommended Video using YouTubeQuery I mean I am using YouTube API .?

I have WPF application which is play a video so what ever video is playing that time I want to show saparetaly Recommended Video  List.?

NOTE: defualt it will give me once video is done, but that would be not usefull in my case.

Thank you.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a YouTube API call to retrieve related videos. See http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Related_Feeds.

Note that you'll probably have to understand how to use the YouTube API in order to make that work. There is a .NET interface to the YouTube API available at http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html.